# Checkin policy to make sure changesets are associated with Tasks

Tags: tfs

I am using Visual Studio Scrum process template and TFS 2013. Is there a way to define a checkin policy that would constraint developers to always use a Task item to associate with their changesets?

I have seen developers associated their changesets with PBI and Bugs without creating any Task items for those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do it be defining a Work Item Query Policy.

Here is an example:

1. Create a new query like this (could be more advanced if needed)
   [image: example1]
2. Create the check-in policy and choose "Work Item Query Policy" and choose the query you have just made
   [image: example2]
3. If you now check-in you will get the warning that you haven't associated any items from that query - in this case, any tasks
   [image: example3]

I hope that was what you were looking for :)