# How to allow only task work item to be linked with Changeset

Tags: tfs

Can anyone suggest, 
how to allow mapping Changeset only with task and not CR or Bug directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333650/checkin-policy-to-make-sure-changesets-are-associated-with-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this question  [Restrict particular work item to link with changeset in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598104/restrict-particular-work-item-to-link-with-changeset-in-tfs)

We do not have this kind of build-in feature, if you really need this, you could [submit a uservoice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM and Admin will kindly review your suggestion. For now, you could use the workaround in above link.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you for your suggestions. The query related to - " Restrict particular work item to link with changeset in TFS" is it should not allow a workitem with some particular id where workitem can be either CR or  bug or task.